# Setting up Redmine With the Bitnami stack installer on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, svn, redmine

I'm running into a problem with the Redmine Bitnami stack intaller on Windows Server 2003. Setting up my project, I'm trying to add a remote subversion repo to the project, but it's erroring out. A little googling led me to some discussions on the Redmine site that leads me to believe the issue is caused by the fact that the repo I'm accessing is SSL enabled and the cert needs to be accepted before I can connect.

All the solutions are geared toward Unix/Linux though (i.e. simply su to the redmine user, run svn command line tool and accept the cert.) but I can't do that because I'm running Windows.

How can I store the SVN cert for the SYSTEM user on Windows?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for your manual windows install of redmine did you use IIS or Apache?

Comment: Apache. I wound up using this little book from O'Reilly for the setup.

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/059652854X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running into the same issue as you.

If your not using remote desktop [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/articles/271063.aspx) has a fairly eloquent solution.

```
sc create testsvc binpath= "cmd /K start" type= own type= interact

sc start testsvc
```

The preceding will apparently kick off a command line as the local system. However this doesn't work over remote desktop (it kicks off the process but the command prompt isn't displayed).

For a more direct approach you can use,

```
sc create testsvc binpath= "svn info --username [username] --password [password] --non-interactive --trust-server-cert [svnserver]" type= own type= interact

sc start testsvc
```

Comment: sub question, http://serverfault.com/questions/37929/how-do-you-accept-an-ssl-certificate-through-the-svn-command-line. If I can figure out how to accept the certificate in one command, I can pull this off through remote desktop.

Comment: Note, even after using what I've posted above I am still getting the "The entry or revision was not found in the repository." error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wasn't accessing an SSL repository, but the problem seemed similar. Reading this post I got the answer:

http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/3968

"The trick was to go to the services panel of windows and to allow the mongrel service to interact with the desktop. (It was running on the local system account )."

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it in the local machine store.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but what if you install a SVN client (Tortoise) and accept the certificate(s) permanently there, whilst checking out?

Comment: I tried that with the command line client. The problem was that mongrel was running as the SYSTEM user, and the credentials are saved for the user that the client is running as. This is why I asked how I could store the credentials for the SYSTEM user. At any rate, I couldn't resolve this problem and wound up just intalling all the components seperately. It took a while, but I wound up learning a little about mongrel/ruby installs on Windows and had a lot less trouble than trying to fix bitnami's installer.