# How do you accept an SSL certificate through the SVN command line?

Tags: ssl, svn, command-line-interface

Is there an command line option to auto accept a SSL certificate permanently using the SVN commandline in a way that avoids the prompt?

Comment: Would this be a better fit at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends somewhat on your version of SVN. Recent (1.6+) ones have the usual `--non-interactive` (which you want to use to avoid prompts) and also a `--trust-server-cert` that may do what you want.

Comment: This solution seems to work. Unfortunately the command line certificate accept didn't solve my initial problem. Oh well, at least I know what doesn't work now.

Comment: If this still doesn't work, it may be because you can't access/create the .subversion directory in your home directory. Solution found here: http://chipsandtv.com/articles/svn-invalid-certificates

Comment: The chipsandtv.com link is dead. Is there another source?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120512113710/http://chipsandtv.com/articles/svn-invalid-certificates

Comment: I ended up having to use both options, now it works, thanks!

Comment: AFAICT, this does not accept the certificate _permanently_.

Answer (score 10):

Using `--trust-server-cert` will not permanently accept the SSL certificate. You can permanently accept the SSL certificate via the command line using **Input Redirection** and not using `--non-interactive`.

Here's an example for Unix/Linux:

```
svn list [TARGET] << EOF
p
EOF
```

**NOTE:** The "p" above is for (p)ermanently.

Comment: Well, my version (`1.6.6 (r40053)`) unfortunately simply won't offer the `p` (permanently) option at all. And since this is on an ancient box which I can't update any longer ...

Comment: I do this command:

`svn --username ${user} --password ${pass} --non-interactive --trust-server-cert ls https://my.svn.server/path <<< p`

This 'works', it lists the svn content, but it does not make it permanent... 
I have svn, version `1.10.2 (r1835932)`

Answer (score 4):

My solution uses expect. It isn't secure but it will work when the other solutions won't.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set svn_username [lindex $argv 0]
set svn_password [lindex $argv 1]
set svn_url [lindex $argv 2]

spawn svn --username=${svn_username} --password=${svn_password} list ${svn_url}
expect "(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? "
send -- "p\r"
expect "Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? "
send "no\r"
expect -re "root@.*:\/#"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download the certificate and then place it in the appropriate directory.  Or you can download the CA certificate and then set the configuration option **ssl-authority-files** to trust that CA.

See the [SSL Certificate Management](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn.sslcerts) section in the book.

Comment: I'm in a very strange situation here, see http://serverfault.com/questions/7648/setting-up-redmine-with-the-bitnami-stack-installer-on-windows-server-2003/37938#37938, so I want to be able to pull it off in one command.